# as root using locate command how to locate a file regardless of owner since locate can only find files owned by user "nobody" in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I tried using locate to locate a certain file which is dog.jpg, I just updated the locate database and it does not show up since locate only finds files owned by user nobody, and the file dog.jpg is owned by user vincent. As stated here,

The locate  database is typically built by user `nobody'' and the
     locate.updatedb(8) utility skips directories which are not readable for
     user`nobody'', group ``nobody'', or world.  For example, if your HOME
     directory is not world-readable, none of your files are in the database.
how do I make locate command find dog.jpg even though it is owned by user vincent? I tried adding user nobody to wheel group, it does not show too.

Any other work around or advice? Thank you!

Comment: Some of the statements in your question are incorrect. Locate can find files owned by any user, as long as those files can be read by any user. So are you trying to create a locate database that contains your private files?

Comment: I want locate to find all files in my computer, do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Have you tried running `locate.updatedb` as root?

Comment: I did, but the problem persists.